# Generated Image is showing big numeric value as ############## on linux server

Tags: linux, aspose

I am trying to generate Image from excel sheet and excel sheet contain very big data . but once image got generated it is showing hash instead of numeric value on linux but in window its numeric value coming correctly

```
 ImageOrPrintOptions imgOptions = new ImageOrPrintOptions();
                    imgOptions.setImageFormat(ImageFormat.getPng());
                    imgOptions.setOnePagePerSheet(true);
                    imgOptions.setCellAutoFit(tue);
                    imgOptions.setQuality(20);
                    SheetRender sr = new SheetRender(sheet, imgOptions);
                    System.out.println("Page Count = " + sr.getPageCount());
                    File outputFile = new File(imgFile);
                    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
                    sr.toImage(0, fos);
```

Comment: Maybe the generating function doesn't find a specific font file on the linux system so it replaces missing characters by the with the #-symbol?

Comment: `imgOptions.setCellAutoFit(tue);` is that a typo in your Q, or a bug in your program or do you really mean to pass `tue` as an argument? Good luck.